# Swedish Language Pack SP 2013 - problem with translation

Tags: language

The word "office" is not translated into Swedish in the Organisation chart. The other words is correctly translated. Does anyone know if there is a bug in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of such a bug, the language pack was released mid March.

This leads me to believe you have only installed the "Base" Swedish installation of SharePoint 2013 and you need to install the language pack.

Search for the following in your MSDN:

"Office Server 2013 Language Pack (x64) - DVD (Swedish)"

HTH - Hugh

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I re-installed the language pack, but unfortunately I still got the same problem. All the attributes is correctly translated, except for "Office".

Regards Emelie

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I would raise this with Microsoft Technical support for a resolution. It could be an installation issue or a straight forward missing translation.